# JAVA asks to trust SSL certificate after adding it to keystore

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ssl, keytool

I am new to SSL certificates with JAVA and Tomcat. What I have done is:

1- Generated keystore and certificate using

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA \
-keystore keystore.jks
```

2- After that, I went to the servlet URL using my browser and exported the certificate to

```
path_to_JRE/lib/security/server.cer
```

3- What was happening is that the Internal eclipse browser used to ask me to install the certificate because it's not trusted by the JVM, so I added the exported Certificate to the JVM keystore using:

```
Keytool -import -alias root -file "path_to_JRE/lib/security/server.cer" -keystore keystore.jks
```

I was asked for the keystore password, after that I was asked to confirm trusting the certificate and I said YES.

After that, I tried to open the URL using my internal eclipse browser but It kept ALSO asking me to install the certificate because it's not trusted.
Even with code I still get the following exceptions:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I know I might be doing something wrong as I am not getting the whole idea.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've found the answer,

I have no idea why was I adding the exported certificate to another keystore other than the JVM keystore. So the importing command should be:

```
Keytool -import -alias root -file "JRE_HOME/lib/security/server.cer" -keystore JRE_HOME/lib/security/cacerts"
```